# Sending an HTML Email through PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell, email

I have the following code that is sending an email, but the body element is emailing with all of the HTML formatting such as `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>HTML TABLE</title> </head><body> <h2>Folders older than 30 days</h2>` (note that is not the whole email. For the entire email see below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>HTML TABLE</title> </head><body> <h2>Folders older than 30 days</h2>
<div>
    Folders were removed on - now
    <br></br>
    Location: \\Server01\XFER\Cory
</div>
<br></br> <table> </table> </body></html>
```

[Photo of Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btxKk.png)

How do I get the HTML to work?

Here is the code:

```
$EmailFrom = “testing1@outlook.com”

$EmailTo = “testing1@outlook.com”

$Subject = “Test”

$body = ConvertTo-Html -PreContent @"
 <h2>Folders older than 30 days </h2>
<div>
    Folders were removed now
    <br> </br>
    Location: here
</div>
 <br> </br>
"@

$SMTPServer = “smtp.outlook.com”

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)

$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("testing1@outlook.com", "powershell")

$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body )
```

Answer (score 1):

The smtpClient method 'send' supports an object of the type mailMessage:

```
Send(MailMessage)   
Sends the specified message to an SMTP server for delivery.
```

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?view=net-6.0)

There you can specify the property IsBodyHmtl.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml?view=net-6.0)

But as you are on PowerShell you could simply use the cmdlet `send-mailmessage` there you have the parameter 'BodyAsHtml'.

Comment: FYI --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage

Warning  

The Send-MailMessage cmdlet is obsolete. This cmdlet does not guarantee secure connections to SMTP servers. While there is no immediate replacement available in PowerShell, we recommend you do not use Send-MailMessage. For more information, see Platform Compatibility note DE0005.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$EmailFrom = “testing1@outlook.com”

$EmailTo = “testing1@outlook.com”

$Subject = “PowerShell Email”

$body = ConvertTo-Html -PreContent @"
 <h2>Folders older than 30 days </h2>
<div>
    Folders were removed now
    <br> </br>
    Location: here
</div>
 <br> </br>
"@

$EmailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$EmailMessage.From = $EmailFrom
$EmailMessage.To.Add( $EmailTo)
$EmailMessage.Subject = $Subject
$EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$EmailMessage.Body = $body

$SMTPServer = “smtp.outlook.com”

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)

$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object          
System.Net.NetworkCredential("testing1@outlook.com", "P@ssw0rd")

$SMTPClient.Send($EmailMessage)
```