# Using PowerShell, how do I send an Outlook email with the content from an external HTML file?

Tags: html, powershell, outlook, html-email, office-automation

I am trying to send a Outlook email in PowerShell using an external HTML file with the Outlook Object Model. Currently I'm only able to get the HTML working if I provide it directly through a Here-String, as seen below:

```
$Example = "Example"
$body = @"
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example HTML $</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>$Example</H1>
</body>
</html>
"@

#Set HTML Body
$mail.HTMLBody = $body
```

I thought a very simple approach would be to just grab the content of the file as seen below:

```
$HTMLPath = "C:\Users\username\htmlfolder\outlookmessage.html"

$body = Get-Content $HTMLPath

$mail.HTMLBody = $body
```

However the HTMLBody method is not recognizing the $body as HTML, and returns a null value for the email's body.

How would I go about feeding the external html file into the script rather than hardcoding the html?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73938651/sending-an-html-email-through-powershell/73939498#73939498

Comment: @Toni I am using the Outlook Object model rather than SMTPClient

Comment: then it makes sense that you add that code to you question...

Comment: Do you mean you are not seeing anything in plain text `$mail.Body`? Tah tis to be expected - it will be populated after you call `Save`.

Comment: Are you sure the content of the file is read correctly? Have you tried setting the `HTMLBody` property to anything simpler from a string variable? Where and when do you call the PS script for automating Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting the `HTMLBody` property to any basic HTML string rather than relying on the external content read from a file. For example, you may try using the following sequence of actions to check how the property is working:

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties. 
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 
 'Create email item 
 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 With objMail 
   'Set body format to HTML 
   .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
   .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>" 
   .Display 
 End With 
 
End Sub
```

Due to the fact that the Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, you may find the required sequence of calls to set up the message body correctly.

---

Also be aware that Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.